# Zend Framework 2 fails to render view, resolver could not resolve to a file. Why?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

For learning purposes, I am trying to create a module in Zend Framework 2 from scratch, but I can't get it to render a view. It always throws this error:

```
Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "my-module/index/index"; resolver could not resolve to a file
```

I understand what the error says: The view file corresponding to the request is missing, but I don't understand *why* this is happening – to me, everything is in place. Probably I have just overlooked something, but I can't seem to find it.

My `module.config.php` looks like this:

```
<?php

return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'MyModule\Controller\IndexController' => 'MyModule\Controller\IndexController'
        ),
    ),

    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'my-module' => array(
                'type' => 'literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/my-module',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'MyModule\Controller\IndexController',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ),
                )
            ),
        ),

        'view_manager' => array(
            'template_path_stack' => array(
                __DIR__ . '/../view',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

My view is located in `module/MyModule/view/my-module/index/index.phtml`.

I also tried `module/MyModule/view/my-module/index/index/index.phtml`, but that looks wrong to me and also does not work – why is the view expected there? Where is my config or file/folder structure wrong – why can't the framework find the correct view file?

Maybe also take a look at the controller:

```
namespace MyModule\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `view_manager` configuration is in the wrong place, you've put it inside the `router` configuration, which means your template folder is never added to the stack. Move the key ...

```
<?php

return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'MyModule\Controller\IndexController' => 'MyModule\Controller\IndexController'
        ),
    ),

    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'my-module' => array(
                'type' => 'literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/my-module',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'MyModule\Controller\IndexController',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ),
                )
            ),
        ),
        // view_manager config doesn't belong here
    ),
    // correct place for view_manager config is here
    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```